# Retrieve all user attributes and user Roles into JWT self-contained

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Which configuration needs to put, to retrieve all user attributes (Claims) and associated user Roles into JWT acces_token self-contained on OAuth 2 authentication patterns ?
Please note that I am into a multi-tenant configuration, with only one Service Provider where we have configured Inbound Authentication Configuration to OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration, with OAuth-2.0.

Action that has been realised:
1. Specify Requested Claims into Service Provider (use Local Claim Dialect), see below
[Service Provider Claim Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6lKQ.jpg)

2. Verify if default information is present into Registry, section: /_system/config/oidc into openid property:

   openid=sub,email,email_verified,name,family_name,given_name,middle_name,nickname,preferred_username,profile,picture,            website,gender,birthdate,zoneinfo,locale,updated_at,phone_number,phone_number_verified,address,street_address,country,formatted,postal_code,locality,region

3.Retrieve an acces_token https://{{auth0_domain}}/oauth2/token
Each time we have only :

```
{
  "sub": "SANDBOX-TEST.COM/usertest@sandbox-test.com",
  "aud": [
    "Y058MDvS1NSe_NrqSV84vDJ6JHga"
  ],
  "azp": "V0458MDvS3NSe_NrqSE84vDJ8JHga",
  "iss": "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token",
  "exp": 1519148273,
  "iat": 1519144673,
  "jti": "4366e42c-48b1-42c6-bf52-a084f1521851"
}
```

Any help/ideas is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the latest IS version. I will give you few tips to troubleshoot this issue.

1. Make sure the user that you trying to authenticate do have values for given claims. You can do this by login in to admin portal of Identity Server and viewing the user profile of the specified user.
2. In "/_system/config/oidc" claims are given in OIDC dialect. Make sure you have correct mapping to local claim dialect to the respective OIDC claim in the claim configurations section.
3. Since this is OIDC make sure you pass the "openid" scope.